# xsl:when in existing XSLT seemingly without boolean expression

Tags: xml, xslt, ssis, xml-parsing

In a project of mine I have to extend some XSLT files, which have been created by some third party provider quite some time ago - in other words: I can not simply ask the provider for more information.

However, I stumbled across the following:

In this project a huge number of XML files is interpreted and loaded into a database. In order to do so, something like 6 "interlinked" XSLT files are used, which feature numerous templates, variables, conditions, and so on. The following code block gives me a headache:

```
<xsl:variable name="Var1">
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="SomeText">true</xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>false</xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>
```

As far as I understood (and if I'm not totally mistaken) this code is used to determine, which value the new variable "Var1" should recveive. But the section

```
<xsl:when test="SomeText">
```

Doesn't make any sense to me. `SomeText` is not a boolean expression isn't it? Furthermore, it's not a variable, parameter, or whatever which could be evaluated by test=". The only thing in all XSLT files with the same name "SomeText" is one of the templates.

So, can `xsl:when` be used this way in ordere to check if a template has been called? Or am I following a false trail and "SomeText" has to be something in the XML files?

Comment: Does `SomeText` correspond to a node in any XML based on the XPath context wherever this `Var1` is defined? That is a valid check and the test would return `true` if the node exists else `false` and subsequently set value in `Var1`.

Comment: @AniketV I couldn't find any node in any XML file with the same name. BUt I only checked 800 of several 1000... anything else ecept a node which would make this check valid? Could it also be a check on the Template with the same name? As far as I understood, the called template is dependent on yet another condition. One template has the same name as SomeText...

Comment: @Tyron78 - Only the existence of an element named `SomeText` in the XML could possibly make this be set to "true" (and even then it would have to be a child of the currently matched node). If there is a template named `SomeText` then it would make no difference whatsoever. Possibly the people who wrote the original XSLT got confused.....?

Comment: Thanks. I will try and search several 1000 files if somewhere `<SomeText` is included... first test on 900 files didn't return any result...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In

```
<xsl:when test="SomeText">true</xsl:when>
```

when the context node has a child element named `SomeText`, the *string* `"true"` is returned.

So for,

```
<xsl:variable name="Var1">
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="SomeText">true</xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>false</xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>
```

`$Var1` will have the string value of `"true"` for the above condition and `"false"` otherwise.

Comment: Thanks. I will try and search several 1000 files if somewhere `<SomeText` is included... first test on 900 files didn't return any result...